# Magneto 2: How to Add custom text after product list in product list page?

Tags: magento2

How to add custom text after product list on the product list page?

In this picture **custom text** i want to add before pagination

[image]

I am trying this. But not done
**catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceContainer name="category.products">
            <referenceContainer name="category.products.list">
                <block class="MDC\CategorySeo\Block\SeoCustomtext" before="product_list_toolbar" name="bottom.description" template="MDC_CategorySeo::product/list/bottom_description.phtml"/>
            </referenceContainer>
        </referenceContainer>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: is this your question or you are just informing to all? @vivek

Comment: @RonakChauhan thank you so much for guide me. Now Question is updated now, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can change code like this one :

```
<body>
   <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
        <block class="MDC\CategorySeo\Block\SeoCustomtext" after="-" name="bottom.description" template="MDC_CategorySeo::product/list/bottom_description.phtml"/>
   </referenceBlock> 
</body>
```

Comment: It's not showing the same problem.

Comment: confirm your path of file is correct and you run the deploy and upgrade command as well.

Comment: app/code/MDC/CategorySeo/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml it's path of file. and also runing the deploy and upgrade command

Comment: I update the answer, check if that work for you.

Comment: It's not showing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="main">

            <block class="MDC\CategorySeo\Block\SeoCustomtext" after="-" name="bottom.description" template="MDC_CategorySeo::product/list/bottom_description.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: It's not showing the same problem.

Comment: I dont understand, you want it to show a problem?

Comment: custom text i want to show before pagination. you can check in the image in question.

Comment: Then It looks like your block class is wrong. Can you post the code from your block class? And what problem is showing? Is there an error?

Comment: And did you flushed the cache? Are you in developer mode or production?